# How to know when to manually release liquibase lock

Tags: liquibase

I have a server running liquibase upgrades during it's startup. We rely on the built-in locks to prevent 2 instances of our server that are running in parallel to apply the same changes.

Problem is - what happens if I run my server and during it's work it is restarted. In this case the lock wasn't released. 
I can't simply run "release lock" logic in code during startup as I can't know that the lock is there due to error case rather than simply another server is currently running the lock.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my project, we had same issue and we decided to run liquibase from command line as part of our Ansible deployment rather than let the app instance doing it.

Comment: Thanks @GaëlMarziou - we don't have such an option in our deployment I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some extra logic and do something based on how long it has been locked. That's the only thing I can think of. If history shows that all your updates take < 30 minutes, and the lock has been there for more than 30 minutes, then release the lock.